# C to Python code conversion(print address-like values)

Tags: python, c, code-conversion

I am trying to convert the following code from c to Python. The C code looks like:

```
  seed = (time(0) ^ (getpid() << 16));
  fprintf("0x%08x \n", seed);
```

that outputs values like 0x7d24defb.

And the python code:

```
  time1 = int(time.time())
  seed  = (time1 ^ (os.getpid() <<16))
```

that outputs values like: 1492460964

What do i need to modify at the python code so I get address-like values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the way the value is displayed. The `%x` flag in `printf`-functions displays the given value in hexadecimal. In Python you can use the [`hex`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hex) function to convert the value to a hexadecimal representation.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent Python code to: `fprintf("0x%08x \n", seed);`

```
>>> '0x{:08x}"'.format(1492460964)
'0x58f525a4"'
```

Note that `hex()` alone won't pad zeros to size 8 like the C code does.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this is what you what:

```
>>> n =hex (int(time.time()) ^ (os.getpid() <<16))
>>> print n
0x431c2fd2
>>>
```